# Collision Rate With NTLMv2 Hashing Technique In Windows

Tags: security, windows-7, hash, ntlmv2

Im doing a research assignment at Uni where i am investigating hash functions.

With SHA1 and (from what i can understand) all hash techniques there is (incredibly rarely) hash collisions.
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297960/hash-collision-what-are-the-chances)

Can anyove give me a figure of how likely a hashing collision occurs in NTLMv2 (used in windows 7)?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Probability of collisions happen randomly, or how often an attacker needs to try to get one?

Comment: Hi CodeInChaos, the probability of collisions happening randomly would be great. I know NTLMv2 uses 3 MD4 functions to achieve the hash.

Comment: And why are you interested in collisions of password hashes? That's quire irrelevant in practice. What's interesting is a pre-image attack.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up CodeInChaos. All i was looking for is a figure to demonstrate how incredibly rare random collisions happen. Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

NTLMv2 is an [hmac-md5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM#NTLMv2) implementation.  It should be noted that [collisions do not affect HMACs](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html).  In order for an attacker to generate a collision for an [md5 has a complexity of (2^24.1)/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5#Security)=`2^23.1`,  however i don't believe such an attack can be mounted against NTLMv2.  So iI believe the answer is (2^128)/2=`2^127`.  This number is thinking of md5 as an ideal message digest function,  and of course no such ideal function can exist.

Division by 2 is done to account for the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: Just clarifying/extending what you said: The probability is 1/2^128 for two different inputs to have the same hash, but you only need about 2^64 hashes to get a collision(see birthday paradox)

Comment: @CodeInChaos Aaah yes you are correct about accounting for the birthday paradox.  However, your math is incorrect, 1/2^128 is a very small decimal.  But in fact the probability should be 1/2 of the total.

Comment: What do you mean by 1/2 total? Birthday paradox doesn't divide the possibilities by half, but the bits. Since you need about Sqrt(x) hashes so for x=2^128 you need sqrt(x) = Sqrt(2^128) = 2^(128/2)=2^64 hashes. But that Sqrt is only an approximation, and you need to be able to keep 2^64 hashes saved.

Comment: @codeinchaos I still think its the 50% mark unless you have a link to back your statement.  Also (1/2)^128=.00000000000000000000000000000000000000293873588.

Comment: @Rook: your own link shows that it is the square root that approximates the number of hashes that need to be saved until a collision is found.

Comment: @GregS I am sorry but i do not see a square root,  However I see the combinatorial 23c2. Could you be more specific.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for your comments. Just to clarify, im not looking for the minimum required for an attack, just an indication of how unlikely a collision would happen 'out in the wild'. Thanks Again

Comment: @Tom Okay the answer is never even after many millions of years.

Comment: @Rook Fair enough, Thanks Rook